# jQuery - how to hide a DIV element only when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `DIV` element that appears when a certain action is performed.  For the sake of simplicity, I wrote a very simple routine that mimics the issue I'm running into.  The problem I am facing, however, is that when you click inside the `DIV` element (and outside the `textarea`), it will hide the `DIV` anyway.

Here is the code below:

```
<body>
outside div
<br><br>

<a href="#" id="wrap_on">make inside appear</a>
<br><br>

<div id='wrap' style='background:red;display:none;padding:10px;width:155px'>
    <textarea id='inside'>inside div</textarea>
    <div id='inside2'>also inside div -- click me</div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrap_on').click(function() {
        $('#wrap').show();
        $('#inside').select().focus();    
    });

    $('#inside2').click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });

    // #inside2 does not work but #wrap does hide
    $('#wrap').focusout(function() {
        $('#wrap').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Or you can tinker with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hQjCc/

Basically, I want to be able to click on the text "also inside div -- click me" and have the alert popup.  However, the `.focusout` function is preventing it from working.  Also, I want to hide the `#wrap DIV` if you click outside of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide DIV when click outside it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-div-when-click-outside-it)

Comment: not a duplicate--I tried that solution and it doesn't work for me; unless I'm doing something wrong.  Here is my implementation: jsfiddle.net/hQjCc/2

Comment: hahaha. another person playing with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var t = (e.target)
        if(t!= $("#inside").get(0) && t!=$("#inside2").get(0) && t!=$("#wrap_on").get(0) ) {
            $("#wrap").hide();
        }
});
```

this should work after all.

http://jsfiddle.net/hQjCc/4/

Answer (score 0):

See this other stack overflow question: [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-div-when-click-outside-it)

Comment: That also doesn't work. Clicking outside the DIV doesn't hide it at all, but the alert does show.  http://jsfiddle.net/hQjCc/2/